# gematria function - processing a text according to numerical values

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I'm trying to process a text, i.e. the Bible, extracting the numerical values of the letters of its words, according to a dictionary:

```
def gematria(book):

    dict = {
              'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 
              'f':80, 'g':3, 'h':8,'i':10, 'j':10,
              'k':20, 'l':30, 'm':40, 'n':50, 'o':70,
              'p':80, 'q':100,'r':200, 's':300,
              't':400, 'u':6, 'v':6, 'w':800, 'x':60, 
              'y':10, 'z':7
           }
```

Using the Nltk module, I've come down to:

```
raw = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw(book)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
words_and_numbers = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
words = [w for w in words_and_numbers if re.search('[^0-9:0-9]', w)]
vocab = sorted(set(words))
nested = [list(w) for w in vocab]
```

I end up with lists with strings for each word's letters, 
i.e. `[['h', 'o', 'l', 'y'],['b', 'i', 'b', 'l', 'e']...]`

In order to process individual words and have their numerical values, the following list comprehensions, followed by the function `sum()`, work:

```
word_value_1 = [dict[letter] for letter in nested[0]]
sum(word_value_1)

word_value_2 = [dict[letter] for letter in nested[1]]
sum(word_value_2)

(...)
```

QUESTION: How can I write a single list comprehension, or a loop, that returns me the numerical values for all of the words in a book, in a big list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, `nested = [['h', 'o', 'l', 'y'],['b', 'i', 'b', 'l', 'e']]`

```
print [sum([dict[letter] for letter in word]) for word in nested]
```

**output**

```
[118, 49]
```

Comment: @data_garden is this what you're expecting?

Comment: just updating: my dictionary items had also an issue. when you tokenize large texts, you must mind punctuation. even your list comprehension at first generated this `KeyError: '.', or '!'`. in order to mend this, you either remove them from the processed text using regular expressions, or attribute value "0' to punctuation in the dictionary. thanks again @Ashoka Lella